# How to run bash scripts via NPM in Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, npm

I am unable to properly run bash scripts with NPM within a Docker container. If NPM is used to run a bash script then it runs it as a nameless user with ID 1000 that cannot use `sudo` to change file permissions and cannot call further NPM scripts.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y zip mariadb-client git sudo
RUN adduser root sudo
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc && nvm install node
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
networks:
  foundation:
  
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
    container_name: '${APP_NAME}-server'
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT}:80'
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
      - 'DATABASE_URL=mysql://${MYSQL_USER}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD}@db_server:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?serverVersion=10.7'
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/server/apache/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./docker/server/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/extra-php-config.ini
    depends_on:
      db_server:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - foundation

  db_server:
    image: mariadb:10.7
    container_name: '${APP_NAME}-db'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${MYSQL_DATABASE}'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db/mariadb/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - foundation

volumes:
  db_data:
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@foundation/foundation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Foundation PHP web app",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "install-app": "bash ./install.sh",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.17",
    "webpack": "^5.59.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

install.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
read -p 'Enter Apache user:group [www-data:www-data]: ' usergroup
usergroup=${usergroup:-www-data:www-data}
sudo chmod 774 storage && sudo chown $usergroup storage
sudo chmod 774 tmp && sudo chown $usergroup tmp
touch log/errors.log && sudo chmod 664 log/errors.log && sudo chown $usergroup log/errors.log
touch log/exceptions.log && sudo chmod 664 log/exceptions.log && sudo chown $usergroup log/exceptions.log
npm i && npm run prod
```

```
root@0021ca12a934:/var/www/html# npm run install-app

> @foundation/foundation@1.0.0 install-app
> bash ./install.sh

Enter Apache user:group [www-data:www-data]: 
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
./install.sh: line 9: npm: command not found
```

And if I try to call the install script directly:

```
root@0021ca12a934:/var/www/html# bash ./install.sh
Enter Apache user:group [www-data:www-data]: 

up to date, audited 373 packages in 1s

53 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> @foundation/foundation@1.0.0 prod
> webpack --mode=production

/usr/bin/env: 'node': Permission denied
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? It seems like you should probably use a multi-stage build to run a _Node_ image then copy just the built assets over to the final PHP image (e.g. [this](https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/main/Dockerfile) is Node -> Nginx but shows the overall process).

Comment: I have a repo that uses an install script to create certain files, set the ownership of folders (so that apache can write to it), create an environments file using the parameters you pass it, install the database, and create a default admin user. It works perfectly when run "normally" on a LAMP stack, but I'm struggling to get it working in Docker.

Comment: You shouldn't just treat the container the same as a VM/VPS, you have lots of other options and need to be thinking about things like layer caching and minimising the surface area. In general you _don't_ want to be installing multiple different toolchains in one container, for example, and shouldn't have non-production dependencies in the final image.

Comment: And the database should be outside the container entirely, provided as a service (in a separate container or elsewhere) using an env var to configure the connection. You only want one process per container.

Comment: It's weird that the prompt - `root@100cd3b962ab:/var/www/html#` - indicates that you're root and whoami says you're user 1000. What does the `test` script in your package.json do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The database is in a separate container. I've added the `docker-compose.yml` to make this clear.

Comment: @HansKilian `"test": "bash ./test.sh"`. When the bash script is run via `npm` like this it says user ID 1000. When run directly from root it says root.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - you're talking about running bash scripts with NPM but we can't see the package file and the script itself seems to be calling straight back to NPM. You probably don't need to do most of this in Docker, but without more context it's hard to say what the right solution is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Done.

Comment: You most likely don't need to do any of that user and directory permission management (or if you do, you should get a better base image). And again the Node stuff should probably be happening in a different stage entirely.

Comment: Scanning through this briefly, my very first suggestion would be to remove the word `sudo` literally everywhere it appears – do not install the `sudo` tool, do not manipulate a `sudo` group, do not run commands with `sudo` – but do use `USER root` in the Dockerfile if you're not root and need to become root to do an installation.

Comment: The first thing I would try is running the npm scripts locally, outside docker.  You could try replacing'bash' with 'sh'. Within Docker - Have you copied the bash script and allowed permission to execute - chmod +x script.sh. Where is your cmd to run the actual node script? Also why use nvm in docker and not just install node. Or better yet use multistage build - using 2 FROM: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/. You can also force npm script/node server to exit with: exit 0 once job is complete. Note: set - e in bash script ends the whole thing if one error.